# Non specific index of a list - python

Tags: python, list, indexing

Not sure how to describe what exactly I'm trying to convey.

I want to get the index of an element from a list by only searching for a part of it.

Like say "-T4" is somewhere in the list "list" I want to be able to get the index for it by only searching for "-T"

Something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
indexx = list.index("-T")
```

even though the actual element in the list is "-T4"

Comment: Try using a different variable name, `list` is a built-in type

Answer (score 1):

The general concept to which you're referring is a *substring search* of list items.

You would need to iterate over the list and compare each item (you could use a regex, or a string method, depending on how flexible you want it to be) to check to see if the item in that place contains the desired substring.

If you iterate over the list using `enumerate`, it you'll have the index as you go which you can return once it's found (or -1 if not found).

One possible way to implement it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

o1 = ['A3', 'B3', 'C1', 'T2']
o2 = ['A3', 'B3', 'C1']

def partialSearch(obj, key):
    for idx, item in enumerate(obj):
        if key in item:
            return idx

    return -1


print "found: {0}".format(partialSearch(o1, 'T'))
print "found: {0}".format(partialSearch(o2, 'T'))
```

Returns:

```
found: 3
found: -1
```

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

It's returning an integer, the index where the key found (or -1 if not found, which technically could be used an index but shouldn't in this case). This can be used to get the item back out of the list, i.e.

```
loc = partialSearch(o1, 'T')
print "value at idx {0}: {1}".format(loc, o1[loc])
```

This returns:

```
value at idx 3: T2
```

You could also return a tuple from the function, say, `(idx, item)`.

Comment: That works to a degree, but I need to have an integer returned so I can go back to the initial list to grab that element from the list and store it to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:
    matches=[i for i in mylist if "-T" in i]

this goes through each item of mylist `for i in mylist` (calling each item i for a bit), and `if "-T" in i`, it then adds an item to the new list containing `i` (the first `i`).

Answer (score 1):

Through `re` module,

```
>>> l = ['-T4', 'B2', 'C6']
>>> l.index([ x for x in l if re.match(r'.*-T', x)][0])
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(mylist) if "-T" in x]
```

That will return a list of all indices matching the query.